# How to configure AWS Incident Manager to call from same number?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an Android device with call screening and want to all my incident escalation phone calls to ring my phone, but so far all calls from AWS arrive from different numbers.

Is it possible to request AWS to use the same number for its calls?

I'm using AWS Incident Manager with a contact with a configured phone number.

Answer (score 0):

With help from a [redditor](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/vykc06/comment/ig34pxe/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), there is an Amazon virtual contact card available that contains all the phone numbers Amazon uses to make these calls. Adding this contact to my phone allows these pages to skip my call screener.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/incident-manager/latest/userguide/contacts.html#contacts-details-file